# Regex: Match repeated groups with non repeated groups

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I have a Json string that I need to extract some data from using Regex in C#
The string is something like this:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3",
  "key4": [
    {
      "arrayKey1": 1,
      "arrayKey2": "something",
      "arrayKey3": "somethingelse"
    },
   {
      "arrayKey1": 2,
      "arrayKey2": "something2",
      "arrayKey3": "somethingelse2"
    },
   {
      "arrayKey1": 3,
      "arrayKey2": "something3",
      "arrayKey3": "somethingelse3"
    }
  ],
  "some very long text here": ""
  "anotherKey": "value",
  "keylast": "valuelast"
}
```

I want to extract the array's values with named groups, I did it with the following regex: `(?:"arrayKey1": (?<arrayKey1>[^"]+),[\n\t ]+"arrayKey2": "(?<arrayKey2>[^"]+)",[\n\t ]+"arrayKey3": "(?<arrayKey3>[^"]+)")`

This works great and I get each match for each item of the array with 3 groups of each key.

Now I want to add an extra match that will contain only the value of "anotherKey"
I can't get to work, Here are some regexs I have tried but didn't work:

```
(?:"arrayKey1": (?<arrayKey1>[^"]+),[\n\t ]+"arrayKey2": "(?<arrayKey2>[^"]+)",[\n\t ]+"arrayKey3": "(?<arrayKey3>[^"]+)")(?:[\s\S]*)(?:"anotherKey": "(?<anotherKey>[^"]+)")
```

This one does get the "anotherKey", but it only returns the first item in the array, not all of them.

Also: https://regex101.com/r/mfXlRs/1

Can someone put me in the right way?

Thanks

Comment: *I have a Json string that I need to extract some data from using Regex in C#*  - Actually, you need a JSON parser. Like [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c) with some hints on extracting data from JSON strings.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm aware of that, but the problem is I can't use a JSON parser in my situation!

Comment: Sorry, that is not right. In *every* situation when you have a JSON string, use a JSON parser. Always. Unless it is invalid JSON. Again, even then, you should *fix* the JSON and still use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex for `arrayKey1..3` (only) gave **three separate** matches, and in each
match you got the 3 required values.

Now, after you added the fragment looking for `anotherKey`, but at the parent level,
the situation changed.
Now you have only a **single** match, because:

- Your "old" regex matches only the first set of `arraykeys`.
- Then `(?:[\s\S]*)` matches everything up to `anotherKey`, including
  both remaining sets of `arraykeys`.
- The added part matches just `anotherKey`.

Maybe you should perform your matching in 2 separate steps:

- Start from the first (old) match, getting 3 matches for arraykeys
  and store them somewhere.
- Then run the second match, **only** for `anotherKey`.

Adding `+` quantifier to the "old" group will not help, because if a capturing
group was matched several times, then the group would hold **only the last** match.